# How can I use the C++ program to add , delete object in ros gazebo

Tags: gazebo, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
While read the following documentation, I can not know how to use it to create c++ program to add or delete object in ros gazebo automatically by program.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/SpawningObjectInSimulation

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28557/how-can-i-use-the-c++-program-to-add-,-delete-object-in-ros-gazebo/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API) shows which services to call and how and [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) shows how to call a service in C++.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use either the /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model service (for .urdf files) or the /gazebo/spawn_gazebo_model service (for gazebo .xml files). In your code you need a service client for the service, e.g., for urdf models:

ros::ServiceClient gazebo_spawn_clt_ = node_handle_.serviceClient< gazebo_msgs::SpawnModel> ("/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model");

Then you need to read the contents of the urdf file into the model_xml field of a gazebo_msgs::SpawnModel service. The generated service then can be used to call your client:

gazebo_spawn_clt_.call(spawn_model_srv);

---

Originally posted by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) with karma: 225 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on 2012-02-27**:
Can you give me a detail example for URDF file.

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2012-02-27**:
I added a very simple example of a node spawning a urdf model on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UTWJSScZ)

**Comment by [jasonwang538@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/30092/jasonwang538@gmail.com/) on 2017-04-21**:
But I use .xacro file rather than .urdf file. How to use it for the model_xml field in c++ code?
Thanks.